# Parse URLencoded GET string in R into a list

Tags: r, urlencode, url-encoding

I need an an elegant way in R to take a urlencoded string such as:
`test.aspx?title=Pancreas%20Cancer&startYear=2000&dataCSV=461%2C520%2C559%2C627%2C1065%2C1217%2C1323%2C1512%2C2160%2C2554%2C2707%2C3000%2C3495%2C4163%2C4927%2C5237%2C4785%2C5559%2C6490%2C7559%2C5106%2C6358%2C6824%2C7980%2C4873%2C6715%2C7038%2C8156%2C4863%2C6460%2C7244%2C9161%2C5237%2C6176%2C6531%2C9068%2C5628%2C5983%2C5871%2C7951%2C6060%2C6089%2C5520%2C6627%2C5722%2C6099%2C5586%2C5822%2C4185%2C4909%2C5053%2C5273%2C5227%2C6077%2C6681%2C7977%2C`

And get a list back that uses the keys sent in the URL the values sent:

```
list ( title = "Pancreas Cancer",
       startYear = 2000,
       dataCSV = matrix ( c(461, 520....etc), nrows = X, byrow = TRUE)
 );
```

Is there anyway to do this easily in R?

Comment: Are you using `httr`?

Comment: `utils::URLdecode()` will get you started.

Comment: URLdecode was my first thought but it just takes out the url encoded characters like %2c and replaces them with their "readable" value like comma or space.  I need something that actually parses that string into key value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start, not very general really either probably

```
library(RCurl)
string <- "http://stuff.com/test.aspx?title=Pancreas%20Cancer&startYear=2000&dataCSV=461%2C520%2C559%2C627%2C1065%2C1217%2C1323%2C1512%2C2160%2C2554%2C2707%2C3000%2C3495%2C4163%2C4927%2C5237%2C4785%2C5559%2C6490%2C7559%2C5106%2C6358%2C6824%2C7980%2C4873%2C6715%2C7038%2C8156%2C4863%2C6460%2C7244%2C9161%2C5237%2C6176%2C6531%2C9068%2C5628%2C5983%2C5871%2C7951%2C6060%2C6089%2C5520%2C6627%2C5722%2C6099%2C5586%2C5822%2C4185%2C4909%2C5053%2C5273%2C5227%2C6077%2C6681%2C7977%2C"
string <- URLdecode(string)
string <- strsplit(string, "\\?")[[1]][[2]]
lapply(strsplit(string, "&")[[1]], function(x){
  tmp <- strsplit(x, "=")
  val <- tmp[[1]][[2]]
  names(val) <- tmp[[1]][[1]]
  as.list(val)
})

[[1]]
[[1]]$title
[1] "Pancreas Cancer"


[[2]]
[[2]]$startYear
[1] "2000"


[[3]]
[[3]]$dataCSV
[1] "461,520,559,627,1065,1217,1323,1512,2160,2554,2707,3000,3495,4163,4927,5237,4785,5559,6490,7559,5106,6358,6824,7980,4873,6715,7038,8156,4863,6460,7244,9161,5237,6176,6531,9068,5628,5983,5871,7951,6060,6089,5520,6627,5722,6099,5586,5822,4185,4909,5053,5273,5227,6077,6681,7977,"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping R had some package I was unaware of that made this more concise, but this works great!

Comment: The last step for readers is to take the dataCSV and convert it into a vector.  You do that like this:  c(as.numeric(strsplit(outputFromLapply[[3]][[1]],',')[[1]])); Then you convert that to a matrix by passing that output to the matrix method and setting ncol, nrow, and by row = TRUE

Answer (score 3):

`httr` provides a function to parse urls, of which this is an example:

```
url <- "test.aspx?title=Pancreas%20Cancer&startYear=2000&dataCSV=461%2C520%2C559%2C627%2C1065%2C1217%2C1323%2C1512%2C2160%2C2554%2C2707%2C3000%2C3495%2C4163%2C4927%2C5237%2C4785%2C5559%2C6490%2C7559%2C5106%2C6358%2C6824%2C7980%2C4873%2C6715%2C7038%2C8156%2C4863%2C6460%2C7244%2C9161%2C5237%2C6176%2C6531%2C9068%2C5628%2C5983%2C5871%2C7951%2C6060%2C6089%2C5520%2C6627%2C5722%2C6099%2C5586%2C5822%2C4185%2C4909%2C5053%2C5273%2C5227%2C6077%2C6681%2C7977%2C"

library(httr)
str(parse_url(url)$query)
```

Comment: Ah, parse_url is what I was trying to remember, should have since I've used it before, thanks @hadley

Comment: I'll give this a try in the code later today and post my results.